# how to get the specific version of NDK I was using?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I want to know the specific version of NDK (r9d, r10e, r14b staff like that), where I could get this version? I tried:

```
➜  ndk-bundle-origin ndk-build --version
```

and I got this:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-apple-darwin
```

Comment: If you have installed it, you can check the `NDK` installation directory, and there has a `source.properties` file, check the file, you can find the `Pkg.Revision`.

Comment: @H.鄭 it shows: 
Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 15.1.4119039
 but I want get r9d, r10e, r14b, this kind of version.

Comment: 15.0.xxx ⇒ 15a 15.1.xxx ⇒ 15b and so on